# Counting the number of certain characters in an array in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello all so I am very new to VBA but have take some beginner classes in Java and HTML so I Almost know what I am doing.

So I have a cell in which I want to split based on a comma (,)
 and I want to count the number of occurrences of a certain Character and then display that result in another cell. Doing this while going down a column of these rows in that single column.

ex: y,y,y,n,y  =  in cell D6 : 4

Below is the bit of code I have generated with the little bit of information I have learned about VBA online.

[I have also seen this bit of code but it get very complex very fast (link) so if someone could explain that one instead I would be very grateful.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560718/split-comma-separated-entries-to-new-rows)

(I tried to comment on the answer but dont have enough rep to do so)

And please when giving the answer try to explain the methods, I dont have an understanding of what each does, being both new to programming and VBA so in regaurds to your replies see if I am able to figure it out with a bit of a push.

```
    Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

Dim Number As String
Dim Yoccur As Integer
Dim Noccur As Integer
Dim Notapp As Integer


Dim length As Integer
Dim current As String


Dim i As Integer


Dim Row As Integer

Do While Row < 84
For i = 1 To length


'parse data into a array here

'tempArr = Split(X(lngRow, 2), ",")
' would that work if I tried to split based on the comma?


If current = "y" Then Yoccur = Yoccur + 1
If current = "n" Then Noccur = Noccur + 1
If current = "n/a" Then Notapp = Notapp + 1

Next i

Wend


Range("d45").Value = Yoccur
Range("d46").Value = Noccur
Range("d47").Value = Notapp


End Sub
```

Comment: [`Split Function`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) as the name implies, splits text using a delimiter and stores each split item in an array. You can then work on that array (eg. iterating through it to get hold of each value, use count function to count occurrences, etc.) to get closer to what you want.

Comment: Split converts a string to an array based on the delimiter, in your case you could `Dim arr as Variant, itm As Variant` and then `arr = Split(Range("D6"), ",")`. Then `For each itm in arr...`

Comment: Happy to go through the other code (I'm the author) if that helps, but I'm not clear on what you are doing. You have a column of cells, and you want the count of all individual characters in an range entire (by "y", "n" or "na")?

Comment: Hey everybody thank you for responding. 
I modified my code to make it work now (kinda)

But can anyone comment on the rest of the code to see if it was logical?

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help. Note the assumptions:

- Your input is located in column A of the sheet, across multiple rows with no spaces between them and starts at row 1.
- The output column for "y" is D, for "n" is E and for "n/a" is F.

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim row As Long
  Dim c As Range
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim s As Variant
  Dim sumY As Long
  Dim sumN As Long
  Dim sumNA As Long

  ' This is the last row of your input in column A.
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  For row = 1 To lastRow ' Loop all used rows
    sumY = 0 ' Reset for every loop.
    sumN = 0
    sumNA = 0

    Set c = Cells(row, 1)

    arr = Split(c, ",") ' Split the value in the cell (row, 1) on comma.

    ' For each string in the split array, do lower-case comparisons
    ' for "y", "n" and "n/a" and increment appropriate counters.
    For Each s In arr
      If LCase(s) = "y" Then
        sumY = sumY + 1
      ElseIf LCase(s) = "n" Then
        sumN = sumN + 1
      ElseIf LCase(s) = "n/a" Then
        sumNA = sumNA + 1
      Else
        MsgBox "Unknown value!" ' Sanity test if something is wrong with the input.
      End If
    Next

    ' Assign the sums of "y", "n" and "n/a" to columns 4, 5 and 6 (D, E and F).
    Cells(row, 4).Value = sumY
    Cells(row, 5).Value = sumN
    Cells(row, 6).Value = sumNA
  Next row

End Sub
```

I'm sure it's not "perfect" (it's very late -- or early -- here!) but it should work and it should at least give you some ideas on how to proceed from here.

Let me know if you need me to explain anything that's not clear.

---

**UPDATE**

Given the same assumptions as above (you can change column A to column C by replacing 1 to 3 in the column indexing of the code) and your comment about linebreaks if I understood it correctly, the following code will now not only calculate the values for each row but will instead count the occurrences of "y", "n" and "n/a" across all rows and will put the results in cell D1 for "y", E1 for "n" and F1 for "n/a".

```
Private Sub CommandButton15_Click()

  Dim lastRow As Long
  Dim row As Long
  Dim c As Range
  Dim arr() As String
  Dim s As Variant
  Dim sumY As Long
  Dim sumN As Long
  Dim sumNA As Long

  ' This is the last row of your input in column A.
  lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

  For row = 1 To lastRow ' Loop all used rows
    Set c = Cells(row, 1)

    arr = Split(c, ",") ' Split the value in the cell (row, 1) on comma.

    ' For each string in the split array, do lower-case comparisons
    ' for "y", "n" and "n/a" and increment appropriate counters.
    For Each s In arr
      If LCase(s) = "y" Then
        sumY = sumY + 1
      ElseIf LCase(s) = "n" Then
        sumN = sumN + 1
      ElseIf LCase(s) = "n/a" Then
        sumNA = sumNA + 1
      Else
        MsgBox "Unknown value!" ' Sanity test if something is wrong with the input.
      End If
    Next
  Next row

  ' Assign the sums of "y", "n" and "n/a" to columns 4, 5 and 6 (D, E and F).
  Cells(1, 4).Value = sumY
  Cells(1, 5).Value = sumN
  Cells(1, 6).Value = sumNA

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You very much and you code did seem to work.  
  
[but every time the dialog box appears every time even when the inputs are correct and the outputs are correct as well.][never mind the dialogue box works correctly now]
  

Also how would I go about changing the input rows?
I moved my data to column C, so then would I put in a 3 instead of 1?
Sorry Im not familiar with some of these methods.  

[YES! I changed all of the instances of 1 to a 3 and it works just dandy]

Comment: @user2292599: What do you mean by linebreaks? And what error or wrong behaviour so you get?

Comment: @user2292599: About the "linebreaks not working", if you mean that you want to add all occurrences of "y", "n" and "n/a" for all cells and display their number only once for all rows where they occur, then see my updated code. The first code was adding and displaying the sums next to each row, but the second code will display the results only once for all rows in cells D1, E1 and F1.

Comment: I meant line breaks in the comments to seperate my wall o' text to paragraphs.

Comment: Oh, I thought you had a problem with the code... Did it work ok or do you still have a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The code below

1. Sets a range from `D6` to the last used cell in column `D`
2. It joins all the values in this range together into a single string (`strV`) using `Join`
3. It dumps the number of *y* values in A1 by subtracting the length of the string with all *y* characters removed from the length of the unaltered string (more detailed explanation below)

   - `[a1] = Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "y", vbNullString))` puts the number of *y* values in `A1`
   - `[a3] = (Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "n/a", vbNullString))) / 3` puts the number of *n/a* values in `A2` (the `/3` is needed to count removing the 3 character length *n/a* as one replacement)
   - `[a2].Value = Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "n", vbNullString)) - [a3].Value]` counts the number of *n* values **-** the number of *n/a* values in `A3` (as *n/a* contains a *n*)

[image]

*code*

```
Sub QuickDump()
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim strV As String
Set rng1 = Range([d6], Cells(Rows.Count, "d").End(xlUp))
strV = Join(Application.Transpose(rng1.Value), ",")
d = Filter(Application.Transpose(rng1.Value), "y", True, vbTextCompare)
[a1] = Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "y", vbNullString))
[a3] = (Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "n/a", vbNullString))) / 3
[a2].Value = Len(strV) - Len(Replace(strV, "n", vbNullString)) - [a3].Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your response.
I tried to add your code to some of mine and that didnt seem to work right.
So I ended up Copy and Pasting your code to just see if it works but it still doesn't for some reason. it is saying the error in on line 5 and the reason is Invalid procedure call or argument.
Im not too sure what that means, but I shall look it up.
But do you think that may have anything to do with my Class being private in my code?

Comment: Do you have a cloud account you could use?

Comment: Yes I can PM you    Ah it appears you cant PM But I do have a Dropbox account I can use.
Can I upload the file in a way for you to use?

Comment: Yes I do have a dropbox account.

I have most of it figured out and now am just working on how to relay on variable from one class to be used in another