# Mapping and vertically transposing multiple Columns to the same ID in the same row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am attempting to create an Excel spreadsheet that will output lines of MYSQL code.  Currently I am trying to create lines for a mapping table, outputting multiple possible values for any one parent key.

I was given multiple rows with comma delineated values which I separated into separate columns. What I would like to do is: for each value in every column containing text create a row with the parent ID and text next to each other.

Example:

```
1 | Text1 | Text2 

2 | Text3 | Text4 | Text5
```

Will become

```
1 | Text1 

1 | Text2 

2 | Text3 

2 | Text4 

2 | Text5
```

Any assistance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Use VBA on your original comma delimited list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8560718/split-comma-separated-entries-to-new-rows

Comment: This worked fantastically, thank you!